# Why does Date().toLocaleString returns different value in nodejs than browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, datetime, v8

While executing `new Date().toLocaleString()` on chrome returns 
"5/2/2019, 11:55:00 AM",

executing the same code on nodejs returns

"5/2/2019, 11:55:00", without AM/PM

I need to have a 12-hours format date with AM/PM mentioned in nodejs similar to what is returned in browser.

Am i missing something and this is the expected behavior?

Comment: it's implementation dependent

Comment: @appleapple can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: answer posted. put it short, the standard does not put constraint on actual format.

Comment: check your node version. Mine is 8.10 and its returnng the date as AM/PM

Comment: @anubysh you are right, just checked on latest 10.15 and it shows AM/PM

Comment: You may have to pass the locale option: I think `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US')` should return your expected value in all ECMA-402 compliant environments.

Comment: @Kaiido That's exactly what i was looking for, please write this as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: May be on the server the admin has specified a specific date format, 24 hour hour instead of AM/PM.

Comment: @SalmanA I am afraid that is not the case. I was actually not passing options in. browser and some versions of node, took 'en-US' by default but some did not. thus it explains the difference

Answer (score 1):

it's implementation dependent, i.e. different implementation can return different string format.

---

[20.3.4.41 Date.prototype.toString()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring)

> The following steps are performed:
>
> ...
> Else, Let tv be this time value. Return
> ToDateString(tv).

[20.3.4.41.1 Runtime Semantics: ToDateString(tv)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-todatestring)

> The following steps are performed:
>
> 1. Assert: Type(tv) is Number.
> 2. If tv is NaN, return "Invalid Date".
> 3. Return an **implementation-dependent** String value that represents tv as a date and time in the current time zone using a convenient, human-readable form.

---

It seems like there would be a standard format in the future, though.

Comment: from what i understand from your answer, the time value(tv) provided to the function in both cases( browser and nodejs) are different? That is what causing the difference in value returned?

Comment: time is (probably) the same, but the browser is permitted to produce different string.

Comment: I just checked on node version 10 and it displays AM/PM. that clears few things probably.